# PHP __DIR__ of file and backup by one directory

Tags: php

I am running a laravel server using PHP 7. I am trying to require a file using the following:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

The file I am running this script in is located in a folder called public. So therefore `__DIR__` should equal:

```
www.mydomain.com/myserver/public/index.php
```

The path the script should create should be:

```
www.mydomain.com/myserver/bootstrap/autoload.php
```

However, rather than dynamically create the correct path it is treating the "/../" as a literal directory instead of telling it to go back one. So the path I am getting back is:

```
www.mydomain.com/myserver/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php
```

Any ides why this could be happening? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two paths should work identically assuming all the directories exist - is this actually causing a problem?

Comment: `require(dirname(__DIR__) . "/bootstrap/autoload.php");`, `__DIR__` collects the current directory name, using `dirname` will go back one step and get the parent dir

Comment: well `__DIR__` is not `__FILE__` .. you shoud check the man at: https://secure.php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 5):

As per my comment;

`__DIR__` is the current directory you are in, if you wanted to go back one step, you could use `dirname`

This is used such as;

```
dirname(__DIR__);
```

So, if your current directory is (and is where you actively are):

> C:/server/htdocs/system/main/index.php

`__DIR__` will give you `C:/server/htdocs/system/main` and `dirname(__DIR__)` will give `C:/server/htdocs/system/`

Therefore, using the following will do what you need;

```
require(dirname(__DIR__) . "/bootstrap/autoload.php");
```

Answer (score 4):

From the manual for [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and extra / characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname

Therefore the following should work

```
require realpath(__DIR__."../bootstrap/autoload.php")
```

However this should not be necessary since require can resolve relative paths on its own just fine.

Since you are using laravel the recommended way is to do:

```
require base_path("boostrap/autoload.php")
```

However the *actual* recommended way is to sit back and wonder why you need to do this to begin with since if you boot laravel properly it should do all these things for you and you should never need to do `require` on anything.

Comment: Clean, tidy, I like this a lot! +1 as this is a much better way that `dirname(__DIR__)`

Comment: @SamSwift웃 I actually prefer the `dirname` in this case but the Laravel helper looks way better than both other options, to mention all 3 would be perfect tho

Comment: @SamSwift웃 thanks . `dirname(__DIR__)` is also a good way to get the parent directory but will end up messy if you need to go e.g. 3 or 4 levels up. Still the laravel helper is nicer because it uses a path resolved on boot and will ensure it works even if people move the public folder around (as is often necessary when using shared hosting).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `__DIR__` refers to *a directory on disk*, not a URL, and not a file. So this statement is wrong:

> The file I am running this script in is located in a folder called public. So therefore `__DIR__` should equal:
>   www.mydomain.com/myserver/public/index.php

`__DIR__` will be something like `'/var/www/mydomain-com/public'` on a Linux system, or something like `'C:\wamp\mydomain-com\public'` on a Windows system.

The code you have will therefore generate a string like `'/var/www/mydomain-com/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php'`. This path is equivalent, at least on Linux and similar systems, to `/var/www/mydomain-com/public/autoload.php` so **your code should work fine and is the normal way of writing this**.

If you actually want to generate the string `'/var/www/mydomain-com/public/autoload.php'`, you can use `dirname(__DIR__)` as indicated in other answers. That removes the last section from a path, so gives you (using my imaginary path above) `'/var/www/mydomain-com'`.